# Ширина правого блока в приоритете

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

```css
.gl {
   display: flex;
}
.right {
width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class='gl'>
   <div class='left'>sssss sss ssd sdas sss sss ssssd s dasss sssss sssd sda sssss ssss ssd sdas
   </div>
   <div class='right'>///<div>
</div>
```

Не понимаю, как при `display: flex;` сделать так чтобы ширина правого блока была в приоритете. То есть если указано что ширина правого блока 90%. Значит правый блок должен занимать 90% не зависимо от содержимого. А левый оставшуюся часть...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запретить блоку сжиматься при помощи `flex-shink: 0` (или как в примере ниже через `flex`).

```css
.gl {
  display: flex;
}
.left {
  background: lavender;
}

.right {
  background: navajowhite;
  flex: 90% 1 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='gl'>
   <div class='left'>sssss sss ssd sdas sss sss ssssd s dasss sssss sssd sda sssss ssss ssd sdas
   </div>
   <div class='right'>///<div>
</div>
```